# How do I set NSColorWell mode?

Tags: cocoa

I have an NSColorWell to allow the user to change the color of the text.

If I set the default to black, the NSColorPanel which appears seems a little useless to beginners, as the color wheel only shows solid black (which is normal). So I want to set the mode to, perhaps, Crayons. I can't figure out how to do this though - the color panel appears by default when my NSColorWell is clicked - how do I talk to it or intercept it to set the mode?

Comment: I needed to obtain a reference to the sharedColorPanel. To change the mode, I send the setMode message with an integer (or a constant from the color panel modes enum) to the sharedColorPanel.

NSColorPanel *cpanel = [NSColorPanel sharedColorPanel]; [cpanel setMode:7]; // or [cpanel setMode:NSCCrayonModeColorPanel];

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSColorPanel_Class/Reference/Reference.html

(Bad form to answer your own question, but I've finally figured it out)

Comment: You should actually post it as an answer.

Comment: I can't, not yet - I have to wait 8 hours as my reputation is less than 100.

Comment: It's not bad form to answer your own question; it's explicitly encouraged. There's even a section in the Ask form for it (at least for me—not sure if it's on a reputation tier).

Comment: You're right, thanks. http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer and http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I needed to obtain a reference to the sharedColorPanel. To change the mode, I send the setMode message with a constant from the color panel modes enum to the sharedColorPanel.

```
NSColorPanel *cpanel = [NSColorPanel sharedColorPanel];
[cpanel setMode:NSCCrayonModeColorPanel]; // [cpanel setMode:7];
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSColorPanel_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: You really should just use the constant so you or anyone else who looks at your code won't have to look up what “7” means.

Comment: Don't forget to accept your answer! Your question still looks unresolved in a question list (e.g., of search results).